# Post-boot and login notification

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, script, login, startup

I am using 10.10.2 and I have limited experience with Terminal. I would like to create a script which would notify me (on screen) when all of the startup processes are completed, post-login. The boot process on my MBP (mid-2012) is not excessive but I would like to know when the OS is ready to start an application through the dock or other means, e.g. a notification which flashes Ready as a notification: maybe by detecting a certain percentage of CPU idleness?

Are there any simple guides available or can someone direct me to an online resource that could provide a guide to a script that might do that?

Comment: The OS hardly ever is completely idle so there's no real way to tell wether it is still doing any tasks related to startup. I suppose you could write a terminal script that monitors something like disk usage (as I doubt CPU usage is very high on startup-tasks).

Answer (score 1):

For OS X system files you cant not determine the end since it keeps working, but if you have start up apps you can do it for those.

For the OS X you could use the first phase of boot process.

it is indicated in the Console as `bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1428512373 0`

After that the OSX is running mostly customization, like finding and connecting to your network ect..

Or you could move to next stage in the process and monitor the WiFi connection...and so on.

You could use something like this to Monitor Console automatically in Terminal and make sound if certain message comes.

```
syslog -w|while read l;do [[ $l = *'message text'* ]]&&afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Blow.aiff;done
```

Replace "message text" with what you want from the Console log as your trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The Dock should be ready to take commands (e.g. mouse-clicks) as soon as it shows.

If you are keen to know what is going on at login, you could add Activity Monitor to your login items and monitor CPU and disk activity as well as "task build-up" (like seeing what tasks are popping in to the list).

Another approach would be to kick off the start process of login items using a script. I did this once with an AppleScript to make sure applications a) started in a specific order, and b) more importantly not all at once but with a delay in between each of them. If you want to do this, all included login items with the exception of your script itself needs to be removed from the login items in System Preferences.

For AppleScript the language guide can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/AppleScriptLanguageGuide.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, a considered response. I'll take some time for this soon.